# Sumproduct formula with alternative conditions from a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

that's my first question, I hope to be clear enough. Let me know if need clarifications.

I have a SUMPRODUCT formula where I need to use multiple alternative values in one condition (OR like). I have those conditions in a table, but don't figure how to use it in my formula.

Here it is:

[image: Formula]

My formula looks like this:

> =SUMPRODUCT(((DataUnitJAN[Sped A]="C0062158")+(DataUnitJAN[Sped A]="C0062104"))*(DataUnitJAN[Articolo]=[@[Part number]]);DataUnitJAN[Qtà Spedita])

Pointing to the following table:

[image: DataUnitJAN table]

But I would like to make it dynamic on the "Automotive" clients in the following table:

[image: Client Table]

I am using Excel 2016.
Does anybody have a better idea how to handle this in a better way?

Thanks,
Ale

Comment: Better share complete set of data with us since current Screen Shot is unable to figure out the Column to apply Sumproduct.

Comment: Adding a screenshot of DataUnitJAN table, to make it clearer.

Comment: In your print screen...  which cell is the sumproduct() formula is applied to?

Comment: @p._phidot_ it is actually in a third table, I am adding this screenshot too.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(DataUnitJAN[Sped A],IF(ClientList[Client]="Automotive",ClientList[ShipTo],""),0)),--(DataUnitJAN[Articolo]=[@[Part Number]]),DataUnitJAN[Qtà Spedita])
```

Entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

The first argument: [*--ISNUMBER(MATCH(DataUnitJAN[Sped A],IF(ClientList[Client]="Automotive",ClientList[ShipTo],""),0))*] produces an array of Automotive clients from the client list, then performs a match of the Sped A column against this array, which is then coerced into 1's and 0's by the "--".

The second argument: [*--(DataUnitJAN[Articolo]=[@[Part Number]])*] does the part comparison.

The third arugment: [*DataUnitJAN[Qtà Spedita])*] returns the value for the matching rows.

This gives the following results (for the data you provided):

[image]